# redirection and static method asp.net don't work well

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect

Hi i am trying to use a timer to execute it each minute , in the first minute he will redirect me at my first page that what i used but the problem that i get a null Referencexpection in the redirection method

```
public partial class wait1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Timers.Timer t = new System.Timers.Timer(6000);
        t.AutoReset = true;
        t.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(t_Elapsed);
        t.Start();
    }
    private static void t_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx", false);   
    }
}
```

Comment: Please run the code in debugger and check which part of `HttpContext.Current.Response` is null. I guess that will be `HttpContext.Current`.

Answer (score 1):

WebForms (i.e. ASP.NET) apps are not the same as WinForms apps. Because of
the fundamental architecture of the web, they are stateless. This means that
they work in a request / response scenario - a client sends an HttpRequest
to a webserver, the webserver process the HttpRequest and sends back an
HttpResponse. After the HttpResponse has been sent down to the client,
nothing else happens between server and client until / unless the client
sends back another HttpRequest.

When a client makes a request to an aspx page, the Page object goes through
a predefined lifecycle firing events such as Page_Load etc. The very end of
this predefined lifecycle involves sending the HttpResponse down to the
client and then unloading the page. Once the page is unloaded, it's gone.

use

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "redirect",
"parent.location.href='Default.aspx';");
```

instead of response of redirect

Answer (score 0):

You simply cannot do it like that. Once you request a web page to the server and the rendering is done, the client is not connected anymore to the server.

This means that only the client (Javascript) can take actions.

Use the JavaScript set time out:

```
<script>
  setTimeout(function(){window.location='...';)}, 6000);
<script>
```

This is telling the broser: *"in 6000ms run the function"*, and the function is redirecting to the required page.